# How to get a visualforce tab url in apex code

Tags: apex, describesobject, tab

I have a requirement where when I click on a link need to to direct to a visualforce tab. So how to get the VF tab url dynamically using apex code. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: If a visualforce tab is created for the page abc then even /apex/abc will take you to the visualforce tab only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mohith, but my visualforce tab need to get highlighted.

Comment: whats the tab style you have on page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a visualforce tab is created for the page "abc" then even "/apex/abc" will take you to the visualforce tab only.

And to highlight particular tab you will use the following code as below

```
<apex:page controller="abcctrl" tabstyle="tabname__tab" id="ThePage">
```

> **The _tab when appended with actual tabname and used in attribute tabstyle of the page the page will be highlighted with visualforce tab**

Comment: I think this will sort it, I was also thinking about the new Describe Tab feature in Apex, there is a getURL method on that, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeTabResult_instance_methods.htm

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Yep i knew its there but i think what user needs is just highlighting and that should do .Thanks:)